# Cannot change properties of a file on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, microsoft-office

In windows explorer if I try to change any of the properties of a file

[image]

I get this error: "An unexpected error is keeping you from applying properties to the file. If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this problem. **Error 0x80004005**: Unspecified error

[image]

Comment: Is this document located on a network share or are you using a virtual machine?

Comment: It is on my desktop. No virtual machine.